# Is it possible to have different meta tag to render CSS and a different meta tag to render javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an desktop application which is using ie7 engine to render and now We are updating it to ie9 only.

To get CSS3 support We update existing meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />` to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` and it's working fine.

But an issue application has plenty of java script file which written based on ie7 render engine, that's why it's throwing many run time errors. it'll take a lot of time to fix.

So, Is there any way which can force all java script to use ie7 meta or engine while rendering?

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: no there isn't a way. You cannot

Comment: Sounds like the JS needs a re-write.

Comment: yes, Thanks guys...